# query_posts() ALWAYS displays something?

Tags: query-posts, loop, query

OK, I'm using posts_query() to display posts.

The problem is, at least in my case, posts_query() always outputs something.

For example:

```
<?php

    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts("posts_per_page=1&paged=$paged");
    global $more;
    $more = 0;

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
        <!--- DO NOTHING ! -->
    <?php endwhile ?>
```

Displays raw first part of a post (and without $more = 0 the whole post).

Why is it happening?

I want to style the output on my own, but I'm not able to, because for example:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
         <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
         <h3><?php the_content( __( '') ); ?></h3>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Gives:

```
<h1>MyTitle</h1>
<h3>something something something something something</h3>
<p>something something something something something</p> <!-- (wherethis line comes from? ;/) ?>
```

PS.

In addition I'm almost sure pagination doesn't work as well, and I believe it should this way? I have around 15 posts to display, I've chosen 1, why there's no navi? :(

The exact code:

```
function posts_shortcode( $atts ) {
     extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        ), $atts ) );  

        query_posts("posts_per_page=1");
        global $more;
        $more = 0;

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
         <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
         <h3><?php the_content( __( '') ); ?></h3>
         <?php endwhile;
}

add_shortcode('posts', 'posts_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> query_posts() ALWAYS displays something?

No it doesn't at least not for me, i've tried the code you posted inside my child theme and was unable to reproduce the issue described.

Firstly, i tried...

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
    <!--- DO NOTHING ! -->
<?php endwhile ?>
```

..and got nothing, so i then tested..

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts("posts_per_page=1&paged=$paged");
global $more;
$more = 0;

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
         <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
         <h3><?php the_content( __( '') ); ?></h3>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

..which produced..

```
<h1>Post title</h1>
<h3><p>post content</p></h3>
```

No stray paragraph of content.

If i had to guess at the problem, i'd say there's a badly coded filter or shortcode at work. Easiest way to isolate the cause (as with any WP troubleshooting) would be to disable plugins and/or switch theme and narrow down which is causing the problem.

**UPDATE:**
Use a new `WP_Query` object instead of `query_posts` and that should clear up the problem.

```
function posts_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    ), $atts ) );  
    global $more, $wp_query;
    $args = array( 
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
    );
    $q = new WP_Query;
    $q->query( $args );

    // Backup $wp_query
    $backup = $wp_query;
    // Fill $wp_query with the custom query
    $wp_query = $q;

    // Do the loop
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) : 
      $q->the_post(); 
      $more = 0;
    ?>    

    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
    <h3><?php the_content( __( '') ); ?></h3>

    <?php 
    endwhile;

    // Output page navi
    wp_pagenavi();

    // Restore $wp_query
    $wp_query = $backup;

    // Restores wp_query global and also resets postdata(may not be needed, but won't hurt)
    wp_reset_query(); 
}

add_shortcode('posts', 'posts_shortcode');
```

Comment: @t31os, OK, so I'm going to investigate my theme then, the query_posts() code above is a part of shortcode in functions.php file. There are no other loops around and that's the problem. [edit] turning off all widgets and plugins didn't help, still searching. [edit2] Deleting all other shortcodes from functions.php also doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @t31os I have edited the first post, I know the shortcode should use return instead of echoing, but both ways give the same results. Can you please check it out for yourself using [post]? Is it also giving you the unknown last paragraph? I've also deleted all attributes to focus on the main problem.

Comment: I'm off into town shortly(lunch/beers, etc..), i'll follow up later this afternoon/evening if someone hasn't already helped you solve the problem by then.

Comment: @t31os have fun! :)

Comment: Late back, but updated my answer. :)

Comment: @t31os you are a genius!oneoneone :D I'm accepting your answer, but have an extra question about pagination - do you know how to "turn it on" using your loop? $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; gives no results. Anyways I AM SAVEEEEEEEEEEDDDDDDDDDDD!!!! :D

Comment: I don't see how you could paginate a query that's output inside the middle of another, any paged query var at that point will refer to the main query, the outer query, ie. the query that is outputting the post(s) or page(s) and contains the shortcode. Your custom query has no real request, because it's essentially injected in the middle of another query(which is determined by the current request). Not sure if that makes much sense(but i can't see how you could realistically paginate a shortcode query). I'm open to ideas though..

Comment: @t31os, I wanted to achieve something like this: http://kaptinlin.com/themes/striking/shortcodes/blog-posts/ :) If I'm unable to use pagination with your code, then I'll try to find a way around.

Comment: @Wordpressor - Ya know, actually it should work if you're using it on a non-paged page, ie. a page with content that isn't span across pages. Adding `'paged' => get_query_var('paged')` inside the args array works for me when testing the shortcode in a page.

Comment: @t31os can you update your answer with working pagination code? I've already added paged to arguments but $paged is always set to "0".

Comment: Have added in, though it's exactly what i posted in my last comment. If you're having problems, could tell me where you're adding the shortcode(inside a page/post/custom type).

Comment: @t31os, so I was right. I'm pasting the shortcode on the normal page (wp-admin > Pages > Add New). I've tried changing name ($q to $wp_query) and if ( $q->max_num_pages > 1) statement. The good thing is this statement is true (so Wordpress somehow knows there is more than 1 page to display) but just simply doesn't want to show the default pagination (I'm using PageNavi plugin that is based on this). This statement echoes everything (like echo 'true';) excepting posts_nav_link(); wp_pagenavi(); etc.

Comment: Ah, so it wasn't a problem of paging not working, just the paging links not appearing, right? You can always test manually by just adding the paged query var onto the url, eg. `example.com/some-page-name/page/2`. Off to bed shortly, but i'll come up with something to fix the issue for you tomorrow(my immediate thoughts would be to do the paging links inside the shortcode, and use a little variable juggling to trick pagination into working - but i'll need to think about it tomorrow).

Comment: @t31os, brilliant! /page/2 etc. thing works! :) I'll try to figure it out once again, but I'm mainly front-end oriented as you can probably see. I owe you a beer. At least! :) The biggest problem here is the PageNavi plugin that replaces the default Wordpress navigation. See you tommorow then, I hope I will finally figure out something on my own :) :P

Comment: Updated answer, just needed to trick page navi by filling up `$wp_query` temporarily and restoring it after printing the paging links. Hope that helps.

Comment: @t31os, works like a charm! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Does same thing happen if you use `the_post()` without *while* loop? Does same thing happen if you don't use custom `query_posts()` call?

This seem awfully like poorly coded filter somewhere in chain, but it's hard to guess location from this.

You could try this code to dump names of filters as they run and try to pinpoint which might cause it:

```
add_filter('all','dump_name',10,0);

function dump_name() {

    var_dump(current_filter());
}
```